# KnockoutJS Hover on UL doesn't trigger, works with CSS:hover?

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

So I've got a organizational system for a geocaching site I'm working on, and for some reason I cannot for the life of me get a onmouseover to fire on this UL.

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: markers, event { onmouseover: highlightLocation }" class="locationList">
    <h3 class="resultTITLE"> <span data-bind="text: title"></span></h3>
    <p class="resultLATLONG">LAT <span data-bind="text: lat"></span>, LONG <span data-bind="text: lng"></span></p>
</ul>
```

If I do a simple CSS :hover pseudo the UL styles will change, but if I try to use it through KnockoutJS, I can't get anything to fire. As a reference with the other code removed, here's what my viewModel looks like:

```
var viewModel = {
   //other code inbetween, linted

   highlightLocation : function() {
      console.log("hovering!");
   },
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

I've been staring at this for the past few hours and I feel like I'm msissing something simple that's staring me right in the face that I'm missing. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really familiar with knockout but noticed a few things and got it to work.

You are missing a colon after `event` and the event is actually called `mouseover`, not `onmouseover`.

```js
var viewModel = {
  title: "title",
  lat: 5,
  lng: 5,
  highlightLocation: function() {
    console.log("hovering!");
  },
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<ul data-bind="event: { mouseover: highlightLocation }" class="locationList">
  <h3 class="resultTITLE"> <span data-bind="text: title"></span></h3>
  <p class="resultLATLONG">LAT <span data-bind="text: lat"></span>, LONG <span data-bind="text: lng"></span></p>
</ul>
```

[(fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/veEW2/99/)

Comment: Note that you can also use `event: { hover: highlightLocation }`.

Comment: agh, that colon did the trick, knew I was looking right past it. Thanks for the help!